# JGroups RpcDispatcher calling method from another class

Tags: java, cluster-computing, rpc, jgroups

How can I get an RpcDispatcher to remotely invoke the methods of a different class? The examples I've seen online all seem to demonstrate how it works when they're all instances of the same class. E.g. [this one from the JGroups manual](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-building-blocks.html) works fine for me because you just start multiple instances of RpcDispatcherTest and they all contain the `print(int)` method.

So how excatly could I get said RpcDispatcherTest to invoke from another, separate JGroups class, e.g. something like the [SimpleChat](https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/blob/master/doc/tutorial/code/SimpleChat.java) example (also from the JGroups manual).

I've tried asking RpcDispatcherTest to connect to the same channel as SimpleChat: `channel.connect("ChatCluster");`. They seem to register eachother, and you can see the updated view with the multiple classes running, but I've failed to get the RpcDispatcherTest to actually invoke a method from SimpleChat, even if I copy the exact same `print(int)` method into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an `RpcDispatcher`, you pass in a channel and a server object as arguments. The latter is the instance on which the RPCs will get invoked. In the examples, it is `this`, but you can pass in any object that implements the methods you want to invoke.